# "There is no row at position 0 how to fix it"

Tags: c#, html, mysql

During find data between two days, getting error "there is no row at position 0"

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Demo"].ConnectionString.ToString());

string str = "select * from sample where name='" + Session["name"] + "' and date between '" + txtfirstdate.Text + "' and '" + txtenddate.Text + "'";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(str, connection);
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

DataSet set = new DataSet();

connection.Open();
adapter.Fill(set);
connection.Close();

//var table = set.Tables[0];
if (set != null)
{
    lblname.Text = set.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
    lbldate.Text = set.Tables[0].Rows[0]["date"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the Error Message. Your result set table has no rows. 
Replace u r if Condition.

```
 if (set.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) {

        lblname.Text = set.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
        lbldate.Text = set.Tables[0].Rows[0]["date"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: @santoshFadia What is the output u r getting in `DataSet` object  `set` .

Comment: I want to display data between two days.

Comment: I am not getting any data.

Comment: Then, What is the `Error`, that u r getting and where.

Comment: this is not execute.  lblname.Text = set.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
        lbldate.Text = set.Tables[0].Rows[0]["date"].ToString();

Comment: Absolutely, that will not execute until u r `dataset` object having data.

Comment: Can to take my laptop on team viewer.

Comment: Listen, Have u executed the same query mySql. If data is not present, then what u will display in both the labels.

Comment: Yes it was working in mysql. data is present in mysql.